# Laravel Eloquent relationship mapping using an array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, mapping

Let's consider I have a model called `Post` and it's table is like:

```
posts:

| id | name   |
|----|--------|
| 1  | spring |
| 2  | autumn |
```

I have another model called `Comment` and it's table is like:

```
comments:
    
| id | post_id | comment        |
|----|---------|----------------|
| 1  | 1       | spring is good |
| 2  | 1       | autumn is bad  |
```

as you see these models are connected by the `post_id` FK
when I want to get posts with comments, I just use:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

in background these queries are running:

```
Q1: select * from posts
Q2: select * form comments where id IN (1,2)
```

and finally **eloquent performs the mapping** to return this output:

```
[
    [
        "id": 1,
        "name" : spring,
        "comments": [
        [
            "id": 1,
                "post_id ": 1,
                "comment" : spring is good,
            ],
            [
                "id": 2,
                "post_id ": 1,
                "comment" : autumn is bad,
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id": 2,
        "name" : autumn,
        "comments": []
    ]
]
```

now let's consider I have an array like this:

```
[
    [
        'id': 1,
        'post_id': 1,
        'author': tom
    ],
    [
        'id': 2,
        'post_id': 2,
        'author': jerry
    ]
]
```

I know if I would had a table called `authors`, it would be easy to connect it with posts! but that's the point: I want to join posts with an array to get an output like this:

```
[
    [
        "id": 1,
        "name" : spring,
        "comments": [
            [
                "id": 1,
                "post_id ": 1,
                "comment" : spring is good,
            ],
            [
                "id": 2,
                "post_id ": 1,
                "comment" : autumn is bad,
            ],
        ],
        "authors": [
            [
                'id': 1,
                'post_id': 1,
                'author': tom
            ]
        ],
    [
        "id": 2,
        "name" : autumn,
        "comments": [],
        "authors": [
            [
                'id': 2,
                'post_id': 2,
                'author': jerry
            ]
        ],
    ]
]
```

and I want to have something like this:

```
$posts = Post::with(['comments', 'authors'])->get();
```

while there is not `authors` table and there is no `Author` model!
it seems I want to use an array as a model!

I know that I can perform the mapping outside of the `Post` model but I'm searching for the cleanest way!

Is there any way to use eloquent mapping in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using eloquent mutators

```
public function getAuthorAttribute()
{
  return //your array or another eloquent
}
```

then add `protected $appends = ['author'];`

and you can use `protected $casts = [];` atribute in model property e.g:

```
protected $casts = ['author' => 'array'];
protected $appends = ['author'];
public function getAuthorAttribute()
{
  return ['your', 'array'];
}
```

use like this : `Post::with('comments')` as author attribute will be added in Post collection